# RxJava Iterate over list making API call for each item and collecting result into single list

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-java2

Am facing strange issue, recently only I started to migrate much of my codebase to reactive so to say am almost new to RxJava, am using RxJava2 for API handling, and below is my problem statement.

API `getGameDetails` returns a `Observable<GameResponse>` which contains information regarding a particular game, need to poll server every 10 second to fetch latest game status, game status response contains `List<Player>` for which system need to query server to check weather `Player` was guest or registered.

As it contains multiple API call, i tried chain them together so in the end I will get `List<Player>` with updated information, below is my try but unfortunately its not working as expected, would need your help in debugging out same.

Thanks in advance.

```
    Disposable d = Observable.interval(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .flatMap(new Function<Long, ObservableSource<GameResponse>>() {
                @Override
                public ObservableSource<GameResponse> apply(@NonNull Long aLong) throws Exception {
                    return  gamePlayManager
                            .getGameDetails(mGameId)
                            .doOnError(new Consumer<Throwable>() {
                                @Override
                                public void accept(@NonNull Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
                                    Log.d("####", throwable.getMessage(), throwable);
                                }
                            })
                            .onErrorResumeNext(new Function<Throwable, ObservableSource<GameResponse>>() {
                                @Override
                                public ObservableSource<GameResponse> apply(@NonNull Throwable throwable)
                                        throws Exception {
                                    return Observable.empty();
                                }
                            });
                }
            })
            .takeUntil(new Predicate<GameResponse>() {
                @Override
                public boolean test(@NonNull GameResponse gameResponse) throws Exception {

                    // check if it has reached X players limit already
                    if (gameResponse != null && gameResponse.players != null) {
                        if (gameResponse.players.size()
                                >= MAXIMUM_NUMBER_OF_PLAYERS_IN_ROOM) {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                    return false;

                }
            })

            .map(new Function<GameResponse, List<Player>>() {
                @Override
                public List<Player> apply(@NonNull GameResponse gameResponse) throws Exception {
                    gameDetailResponse = gameResponse;
                    return gameResponse.players;

                }
            })
            .flatMap(new Function<List<Player>, ObservableSource<List<Player>>>() {
                @Override
                public ObservableSource<List<Player>> apply(@NonNull List<Player> players) throws Exception {

                    return Observable.fromIterable(players).flatMap(new Function<Player, ObservableSource<Player>>() {
                        @Override
                        public ObservableSource<Player> apply(@NonNull final Player player) throws Exception {
                            return Observable.fromCallable(new Callable<Player>() {
                                @Override
                                public Player call() throws Exception {


                                    UserProfile profile = userService.profile(token,
                                            player.playerId);
                                    if (profile != null) {
                                        player.internalUser = true;
                                    }
                                    return player;

                                }
                            });
                        }
                    })
                            .toList()
                            .toObservable();

                }
            })
            .doOnNext(new Consumer<List<Player>>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(@NonNull List<Player> players) throws Exception {

                    // Some code for presenting UI here

                    //
                }
            })
            .doOnError(new Consumer<Throwable>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(@NonNull Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
                    Log.d("####",throwable.getMessage(),throwable);
                    startGameView.showErrorMessage();
                }
            })
            .subscribe();
    subscriptions.add(d);
```

Comment: Why you used takeUntil() operator here?

Comment: I want to stop continuous polling if certain criteria is already met @SagarTrehan

Comment: ok. What is the issue?. Is the continuous polling not getting pausing when the criteria doesn't met?